# Using named_scopes on the join model of a has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, named-scope, has-many-through

I've been beating my head against the wall on something that on the surface should be very simple. Lets say I have the following simplified models:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :memberships  
has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
```

**membership.rb**

```
belongs_to :group  
belongs_to :user  
STATUS_CODES = {:admin => 1, :member => 2, :invited => 3}  
named_scope :active, :conditions => {:status => [[STATUS_CODES[:admin], STATUS_CODES[:member]]}
```

**group.rb**

```
has_many :memberships  
has_many :users, :through => :memberships
```

Simple, right? So what I want to do is get a collection of all the groups a user is active in, using the existing named scope on the join model. Something along the lines of User.find(1).groups.active. Obviously this doesn't work.

But as it stands, I need to do something like `User.find(1).membrships.active.all(:include => :group)` which returns a collection of memberships plus groups. I don't want that.

I know I can add another has_many on the User model with conditions that duplicate the :active named_scope on the Membership model, but that's gross.

```
has_many :active_groups, :through => :memberships, :source => :group, :conditions => ...
```

So my question: is there a way of using intermediary named scopes when traversing directly between models? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```
User.find(1).memberships.active.collect(&:group)
```

and this will return all the groups this user is active in.

Comment: Something similar does work, but its pretty ugly:  

    user.memberships.active.all(:include => :group).collect(&:group)

Comment: Of course... my mistake! You need the `collect` part. It's really not very beautiful...

Comment: It also results in an array rather than a proper collection. Still hoping for more ideas on this one.

Comment: It returns an array of `groups`, isn't it? This is the correct behavior

Comment: Ideally, I would like a proper collection that could be further chained, such as user.memberships.active.groups.find_by_id(23) or some such. It seems like a gap in AR.